# A problem about sums of reciprocals of integers and the number $1$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

**The problems:**

Given $A \subseteq \mathbb{N^*}$ and $A$ is infinite. Find the necessary and sufficient condition of $A$ so that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}$:

$$\left \{ \; (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in A^n \; | \; a_1 < a_2 < \; ... < a_n \; \wedge \; \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_i} > 1 \; \right \}$$

**a)** is finite. (**Solved by TonyK**)

**b)** if not empty, has a minimum in terms of $\; \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}$.  (It's already had a maximum)

$$\text{ }$$

I posed these problems when thinking about their specific case of $A = \mathbb{P}$ (the set of prime numbers). I haven't solved the case yet. All I found is a necessary condition for both problems: $\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*} \; \; \nexists \; (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ $\in A^n$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} = 1$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} = 1$ should be $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} \ge 1$, I think. So the condition you want is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_i} \le 1$.

Comment: Your condition is necessary, but rather weak. In other words, there will be many sets $A$ for which your condition holds, but that set ($S_n$ in my answer) is nevertheless infinite for some $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

The condition you want is $$\sum_{a_i\in A} \frac{1}{a_i} \le 1$$

Define
$$S_n = \left \{ \; (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in A^n \; | \; a_1 < a_2 < \; ... < a_n \; \wedge \; \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_i} > 1 \; \right \}$$

1. Assume $\sum_{a_i\in A} \dfrac{1}{a_i} \le 1$. Then $S_n$ is finite (indeed empty) for all $n$.
2. For the converse, assume $\sum_{a_i\in A} \dfrac{1}{a_i} > 1$ (or the sum does not converge). Put the elements of $A$ in increasing order, so that $A=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots\}$ with $u_1 < u_2 <\ldots$ Then there exists $N$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^N \dfrac{1}{u_i} > 1$. So $S_{N+1}$ contains the sequence $(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_N,u_k)$ for every $k > N$, and is therefore infinite.

Comment: Thanks! The finiteness is unexpectedly easy. What about the same problem with only replacement that is "$S_n$, if not empty, has a minimum $\forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}$"? My necessary condition still holds true. I'll edit the question.